# How to set responsive size to SAPUI5 Dialog with sap.ui.table.Table inside?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have the following fragment with a dialog. If you see, the dialog is bigger than the table (`sap.ui.table.Table`), I need to delete the white, or non-data, spaces:

[image: results of fragment with a dialog]

Code used to generate the above dialog:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:t="sap.ui.table"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt">
  <Dialog title="{main>/textPool/K490}"
    contentWidth="auto"
    contentHeight="auto">
    <content>
      <t:Table id="oInvoiceDetailTable"
        selectionMode="None"
        visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
        rowHeight="50"
        columnHeaderHeight="Auto"
        rows="{ path: 'invoiceDetail>/items' }"
        columns="{
          path: 'invoiceDetail>/catalog',
          sorter: 'COL_POS',
          filters: [{
            path: 'TECH',
            operator: 'NE',
            value1: 'X'
          }],
          factory: '.invoice.tableInvoiceDetail'
        }"/>
    </content>
    <endButton>
      <Button text="{main>/textPool/K066}"
        type="Reject"
        tooltip="{main>/textPool/K066}" />
    </endButton>
  </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I tried with:

```
contentWidth="auto"
contentHeight="auto"
```

but it doesn't work, please any suggestion how to solve this? I don't want to set a `%` to the content because sometimes there are more or less columns...

Comment: Have you tried using a `sap.m.Table` instead? It's responsive by design which might have a positive effect on the container Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to give any width/height options to your Grid Table or Dialog as the sap.m.Dialog is responsive and the Grid Table's columns should grow/shrink to fit the parent container's size.

Giving a dialog 100% width and height will essentially "maximize" it to your screen.

Check this fiddle, the Grid Table has 2 Columns that adjust to the Dialog's width and the Dialog is set to 50% width.
https://jsfiddle.net/abs1337/v9oqbj4z/

```
    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
      title: "Table binding",
      showNoData: true,
      visibleRowCount: 5
    });

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
      label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({
        text: "First Name"
      }),
      template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
        text: "{model1>fname}"
      })
    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
      label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({
        text: "Last Name"
      }),
      template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
        text: "{model1>lname}"
      })
    }));

    var oDialg = new sap.m.Dialog({
      title: 'Responsive Dialog',
      content: oTable,
      contentWidth: "50%",
    })
```

Set the Dialog to 100% width in the fiddle and see what happens.

Although, your best option would be to use sap.m.table which is the recommended table for responsiveness as you mentioned the columns might increase/decrease.

Answer (score 1):

set the `contentWidth` and `contentHeight` of the Dialog to `"100%"`.

and set the `width` and `height` properties of the Table to `"100%"`

that let Table expand to fill the available space inside the Dialog.